# How to filter a product list using v-btn in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, filter, vuetify.js, v-btn

I am currently trying to filter a list of objects by using buttons.

I know that both v-btn and v-card loops are not currently interdependent, but I am unable to figure out how to link both sections to properly show only the correct category when pressing its respective button.

Thanks for the help!

```html
        <v-row class="my-4">
          <v-btn
          v-for="category in categories"
          text
          class="underline"
          route :to="category.route"
          @click="category.function"
          >{{ category.text }}</v-btn>

        </v-row>
        <v-row 
        justify="start">
          <v-card
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product.name"
          class="ma-3 text-center">
          <v-img
          :src="product.src"
          class="mc mt-2"
          >
          </v-img>
          <v-card-title
          class="bold justify-center">
            <h4>{{ product.name }}</h4>
          </v-card-title>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
```

```html
categories: [
                { text: 'All', function: "all()" },
                { text: 'Fruits & Veggies', function: "fruitsVeggies()"  },
                { text: 'Baking', function: "baking"  },
                { text: 'Gadgets', function: "gadgets"  },
                { text: 'Cutting Boards', function: "cuttingBoards"}],  


products: [{...}, {...}, etc]


computed: {
      all() {
        return this.products.filter(product => {
          return product
        })
      },
      fruitsVeggies() {
        return this.products.filter(product => {
          return product.category === 'Fruits & Veggies'
        })
      },
      baking() {
        return this.products.filter(product => {
          return product.category === 'Baking'
        })
      },
      cuttingBoards() {
        return this.products.filter(product => {
          return product.category === 'Cutting Boards'
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) return a dynamic value
When you call `baking` as a function, it should throw an error in the console; it's not a function, but a property

Instead, you could define a computed property called `filteredProducts` that changes filter based on something stored in the data, and loop over that instead

```
data() {
  productFilter: "all"
}

computed: {
  // your computed values
  filteredProducts() {
    if (this.productFilter === "all") {
      return this.all;
    }
    // etc. For all filters
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<v-row 
  justify="start"
>
  <v-card
  v-for="product in filteredProducts"
```

Comment: No problem! I highly recommend reading [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) when you stumble across an issue with Vue. It's concise, easy to understand, and has a wide variety of examples for almost all basic use cases of the framework